# How to get the value of multiple checkboxes only

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the value of multiple checkboxes, but I also have radio buttons included. I try to get the value like this:

```
const inputData = [];

    document.querySelectorAll("input:checked").forEach((item) => {
        inputData.push(item.value);
      });
```

As a result, I get the values of both the radio buttons and the checkboxes.
This is how I created the radio buttons and the checkboxes:

```
else if (i.type === "single-select"){

      for (const o of i.options){

        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        x.setAttribute("id", "radioID");
        x.value = o;

        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode(o);
        y.appendChild(t);

        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.height = "5px";
        div.appendChild(x);
        div.appendChild(y);
        document.getElementById("radioButton").appendChild(div);


        window.data.appendChild(x);
        window.data.appendChild(y);
        window.data.appendChild(div);
      }
    }


    else if (i.type === "multi-select"){
      for (const l of i.options){
        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        x.value = l;

        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode(l);
        y.appendChild(t);


        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.height = "5px";
        div.appendChild(x);
        div.appendChild(y);
        document.getElementById("checkbox").appendChild(div);

        window.data.appendChild(x);
        window.data.appendChild(y);
        window.data.appendChild(div);
      }
}
```

How can I get the values of multiple checkboxes only, without getting the values of the radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector to be more targeted.

```
"input:checked"
```

to

```
"input[type=checkbox]:checked"
```

Comment: Welcome. Please upvote/accept the answer if it fixed your problem.